# JSON array to ArrayList of specific class

Tags: java, gson

JSON

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "product new"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "test12345"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "product new"
  }
]
```

Java

```
 ArrayList<Product> products
 products = new Gson().fromJson(result.toString(), ArrayList<Product>.getClass());
```

how can I convert the JSON array to Product class based ArrayList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

ArrayList<Product> products  = new Gson().fromJson(results, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Product>>(){}.getType());;
```